# Como tratar um array jQuery (remover duplicados e impedir um item de aparecer em 2 arrays)?

Tags: jquery, array

Tenho 2 arrays (like e notlike) e conforme vou dando like ou notlike, ele vai adicionando o item na array, atualmente está assim:

```
//DEFINE ARRAYS
like = new Array();
notlike = new Array();

//SE CLICA NO btnlike VAI PARA ARRAY LIKE
$(".btnlike").on("click", function() {
    like.push($(this).attr('id'));
}

//SE CLICA NO btnnotlike VAI PARA ARRAY NOTLIKE
$(".btnnotlike").on("click", function() {
    notlike.push($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

Aí preciso criar 2 regras:

1. O valor não pode repetir dentro da array, deve ser valor único
2. O valor não pode aparecer nas 2 arrays, se foi adicionando em uma
   array e depois clicou no botão para adicionar na outra array, ele
   deve remover da primeira array

Answer (score 3):

Eu faria algo mais ou menos assim, espero que ajude

```
//DEFINE ARRAYS
    like = new Array();
    notlike = new Array();
    opiniao = new Array(); //crie um novo array para guardar ambos

    $(".btn").on("click", function() { //coloque a mesma classe para os dois botões e separe "like" e "notlike" no atributo data-tipo; por exemplo data-tipo=like
    tipo = $(this).attr('data-tipo'); //aqui coletaremos se é like ou not-like


    if(tipo == 'like') { //se o tipo for like, entra aqui

    if(jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('id'), opiniao) !== -1) {    //vai checar se já tem no array opiniao, que está em ambos
    like.push($(this).attr('id'));
    opiniao.push($(this).attr('id')); //abastece opiniao também que é o verificador
    }
    }


    if(tipo == 'notlike') { //se o tipo for notlike, vem aqui
    if(jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('id'), opiniao) !== -1) {    //vai checar se já tem no array opiniao que tem em ambos
        notlike.push($(this).attr('id'));
        opiniao.push($(this).attr('id')); //abastece opiniao também que é o verificador
    }
    }

    });
```

Comment: legal, vou testar aqui

Comment: Boa sorte irmão! Thumbsup se rolar ;)

Answer (score 1):

Não use `id` para os elementos, porque você estará duplicando id's nos dois botões, o que é errado no HTML. Em vez disso use dataset `data-id`, por exemplo:

```
<button class="btnlike" data-id="1">LIKE</button>
<button class="btnnotlike" data-id="1">NOT LIKE</button>
```

> Se tiver usando a tag **button**, como acima, use `value` em vez de
>   `data-id`.

Use o método [**$.grep()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) do jQuery para filtrar as arrays removendo, caso exista, o valor do botão clicado na outra array.

Ou seja, você verifica se o valor existe na array com `.$inArray` e em seguida usa o `$.grep` para remover o valor da outra array. O código fica bem simples, como mostra abaixo. Dá até para melhorar mais juntando os eventos nos dois botões num só, mas coloquei em separados mesmo para ficar mais fácil de ler.

```js
//DEFINE ARRAYS
like = new Array();
notlike = new Array();

//SE CLICA NO btnlike VAI PARA ARRAY LIKE
$(".btnlike").on("click", function() {
   
   var valor = $(this).data("id");
   
   if(!~$.inArray(valor, like)){
      like.push(valor);
   }
   
   notlike = $.grep(notlike, function(v){
     return v != valor;
   });
   
   // daqui pra baixo é só para ilustração. Não inclua
   console.clear();
   console.log("LIKE: ", like.join(","));
   console.log("NOTE LIKE: ", notlike.join(","));
});

//SE CLICA NO btnnotlike VAI PARA ARRAY NOTLIKE
$(".btnnotlike").on("click", function() {

   var valor = $(this).data("id");
   
   if(!~$.inArray(valor, notlike)){ // verifica se já existe
      notlike.push(valor); // adiciona na array
   }
   
   like = $.grep(like, function(v){ // remove da outra array
     return v != valor;
   });

   // daqui pra baixo é só para ilustração. Não inclua
   console.clear();
   console.log("LIKE: ", like.join(","));
   console.log("NOTE LIKE: ", notlike.join(","));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1. <button class="btnlike" data-id="1">LIKE</button>
<button class="btnnotlike" data-id="1">NOT LIKE</button>
<br><br>
2. <button class="btnlike" data-id="2">LIKE</button>
<button class="btnnotlike" data-id="2">NOT LIKE</button>
<br><br>
3. <button class="btnlike" data-id="3">LIKE</button>
<button class="btnnotlike" data-id="3">NOT LIKE</button>
```